# setLayoutParams throws nullPointerException on Android 3.2

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am customizing my app to show in 2 columns on tablets. I am setting the width of the left and right column by `setLayoutParams`. It is working fine on Android 3.0 and Android 3.1 emulators. On Android 3.2 emulator it gives a `nullPointerException`.

This is part of my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Debug.LogCat(activityName + ":OnCreate");

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // set layout for tablets
    final boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (isTablet) {
        // set screenorientation to landscape
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        // get half screensize
        int width = metrics.heightPixels / 2;
        // set left column to width
        LinearLayout left_column = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_column);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_left_column = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // this is where the NPE occurs
        left_column.setLayoutParams(lp_left_column);

        // set right column to width
        LinearLayout right_column = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.right_column);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_right_column = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        right_column.setLayoutParams(lp_right_column);

    }
```

This is my layout (home.xml) where I have specified the id's left_column and right_column:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center" >    


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_column"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_largeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/largeImage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/largeImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"         
            android:onClick="playSound" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_column" 
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/infoImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/largeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know why it's giving a `nullPointerException` on *Android 3.2*?

Edit: 06-03-2013:
As I said in my answer to dymmeh the boolean isTablet is set in layouts.xml in the folders values, values-large and values-xlarge.
Debugging to logcat shows me that it is going inside the if statement, so that part is working.
But after this I also have a home.xml in 2 folders: layout and layout-land. it turns out that for Android 3.2 it is taking the home.xml from the layout folder instead of the layout-land.
I have tried to put the setContentView(R.layout.home) inside the if statement after setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE) but it still gives NPE.
So I'm continuing my search in why setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE) is not working for Android 3.2.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: [`NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) or [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);  Which folder are you specifying that in?

Comment: I have 3 folders in res: values, values-large and values-xlarge. In these I have a layout.xml which has the boolean:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>    
</resources>

true in values-large and values-xlarge and false in values folder.
    
This part is working as the app is working on smartphones and 3.0 and 3.1 tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

The setRequestedOrientation worked fine, but the home.xml was not taken from layout-land because from Android 3.2 there is a new way of supporting multiple screens. You should then use sw*N*dp as explained in: [DeclaringTabletLayouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

So I made a new folder in res: layout-sw600dp and placed the landscape home.xml in that folder and that was the solution.